# how to get password value by using email entered by user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on firebase database connected with android. How can i get password value from database based on email value entered by user?

My database structure.

[image: database structure]

Comment: I hope, you don't store password in clear text.

Comment: You can loop through all your users and check if the user's email id matches with the entered email then you can return the password

Comment: Like @Henry said, do NOT save the password in the database.  Save the salted hash of the password.

Comment: i need code for help

Comment: Show us what you tried and explain why it did not work.

Comment: mdatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                                user_reg user=dataSnapshot.getValue(user_reg.class);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: i have tried this one. but how can i make it specific to a particular email address