# How can I retrieve values from Firebase database based on email entered by user in text field?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on Firebase database. How can I retrieve values from database based on email entered by user in text field. Below is my database structure. Kindly help.

[image: database structure]

Here is my code:

```
 Ref = database.getReference("Registeration"); 
                        Ref.orderByChild("UserRegistration/email").equalTo(emailval).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                                user_reg user=dataSnapshot.getValue(user_reg.class);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
```

Comment: are you saving the email in firebase?

Comment: yes i am saving all the data in firebase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get password value by using email entered by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48605003/how-to-get-password-value-by-using-email-entered-by-user)

Comment: As Peter and divyanshu have said, you cannot run the query you want on the data structure you now have. For more on that, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested. But what is the meaning of the push ID (`-L...`) under `12`?

Comment: its  not working

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
 Registration
       UserRegistration
               12
                pushid
                  key:values
                  email:emailvalue
```

To retrieve values always you have to go from top to bottom, so you cannot skip any node.

Only `orderByChild(..)` query can skip one node (which means you use this query if you want to get children that are not direct children)

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Registration").child("UserRegistration").child("12");
ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailenteredbyuser).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { 
           String email=datas.child("email").getValue().toString();

          }
        }
        @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

       }

 });
```

As you can see in the above, the reference passes through every node until node `12`.

Then you use this `orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailenteredbyuser)` to get the email entered by the user.

`for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren())` this for loop the `datas` iterates in inside the direct children of `12` which is the pushid that way you do not need to retrieve the pushid to get the values inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this! here I am running for each loop to get each child.

```
Ref.child("UserRegistration").child("email").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    user_reg user=dataSnapshot.getValue(user_reg.class);
                    System.out.println(user.email);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```